# Google Analytics Realtime Sources Missing

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am successfully using the realtime time API across several high traffic domains but one in particular has a problem where very little / no `rt:source` information is being provided. If I query the same pages using the core API the source information is available/correct.

For this problematic domain the majority of the rows returned by the realtime API provide a source as `(not set)`. All pages have correctly implemented manual source tracking:

```
http://www.domain.com/page/?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=med1&utm_campaign=camp1
```

There does not appear to be any differences between all working domains and the problematic one.

So far I have tried:

1. Different utm_medium and utm_campaign values.
2. Reducing the number of dimensions in my RT query to only rt:pagePath and rt:source.

Is there perhaps an analytics configuration value that is different for this domain?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the filters applied to the view?